# Running Automation test on url links that store in a text file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to loop throw a text file that stores a URL links the problem is that every time i run the test the browser opens the API links one after another and closes them one by one, and only on the last one did the test completely and pass. there is a way to fix this issue?

there is my code:

```
@Test
public void JeneratorTest() throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("starting itineraryJeneratorTest");

    // crate driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // maximize browser window

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // open web page by looping on a text file
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("url/Untitled 1"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            driver.get(line);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // click agree to the terms
    WebElement agrreToTerms = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//div[@id='root']/div[1]//button]"));
    agrreToTerms.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are performing actions outside of the `loop`. Call those actions inside the `loop`.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get(line);
   Thread.sleep(500);
   WebElement agrreToTerms = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//div[@id='root']/div[1]//button]"));
   agrreToTerms.click();
   driver.close();
  }
```

It's always better to use `Explicit` wait instead of `Implicit` wait or `Thread.sleep()`.